# Calculating $\int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone help me calculate this integral?

$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}}{x}dx$

I tried this substitution:

$\Bigg(t = \sqrt[3]{x}, t^3 = x, 3t^2dt=dx\Bigg)$

which reduces the integral to:

$\int \frac{\sqrt{t-2}}{t}3t^2dt = 3\int \sqrt{t-2}tdt$

and continuing from here is pointless, because the result (according to wolfram) is waaay wrong. I don't understand why that substitution was wrong...

So I also tried this substitution instead:

$t = \sqrt[3]{x} - 2$

$t^3 = x - 6 \sqrt[3]{x^2} + 12\sqrt[3]{x} - 8$

But this seems algrebraically impossible to me.

Help's appreciated.

Comment: It's $t^3$ not $t$ at denominator

Comment: Why there is t in the denominator ($t^3=x$) . It should be $t^3$

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $6 \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x}-2}-6 \sqrt{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x}-2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}}{\color{blue}{x}}dx$
>
> $\Bigg(t = \sqrt[3]{x}, \color{blue}{t^3 = x}, 3t^2dt=dx\Bigg)$
>
> $\int \frac{\sqrt{t-2}}{\color{red}{t}}3t^2dt = \ldots$

With your substitution, you want $\color{blue}{t^3}$ where you have $\color{red}{t}$.

---

You then end up with:
$$3\int\frac{\sqrt{t-2}}{t}\,\mbox{d}t$$
and you can follow up with e.g. $u=\sqrt{t-2}$ to rationalize the integrand.

Comment: I would follow up with the trigonometric substitution. $$t=2\sec^2 u, dt = 4\sec^2 u \tan u$$ so that gives $$6\sqrt{2}\int{\tan^2 u du}$$

Comment: @interstellarprobe Are you sure? There's no $t^2$ under the square root, just a $t$...

Comment: quite sure. $$\sqrt{t-2} = \sqrt{2\sec^2 u -2} = \sqrt{2}\tan u$$ the denominator becomes $$2\sec^2 u$$ and $$dt = 4\sec^2 u \tan u$$ It all works out great.

Comment: I missed the square, I was en route and reading on my smartphone :o). Yes sure, that works too!